# Getting ImportError even though module is installed

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-debugger

installed :

```
 pip install google-python-cloud-debugger
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): google-python-cloud-debugger in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): google-api-python-client in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-python-cloud-debugger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six<2,>=1.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client->google-python-cloud-debugger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): httplib2<1,>=0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client->google-python-cloud-debugger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): oauth2client in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client->google-python-cloud-debugger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): uritemplate<1,>=0.6 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from google-api-python-client->google-python-cloud-debugger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1>=0.1.7 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client->google-api-python-client->google-python-cloud-debugger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client->google-api-python-client->google-python-cloud-debugger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): rsa>=3.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from oauth2client->google-api-python-client->google-python-cloud-debugger)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplejson>=2.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from uritemplate<1,>=0.6->google-api-python-client->google-python-cloud-debugger)
```

but when trying to import , I get `ImportError: No module named uritemplate`. 
stacktrace is :
`googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 53, in <module>`

the thing is `uritemplate`  is installed:

```
pip install uritemplate
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): uritemplate in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplejson>=2.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from uritemplate)
```

direct import of `uritemplate` also doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. 
`uritemplate` was downloaded to my files system. 
after solving that , the same goes for `oauth2client` 
which I had to update . downloaded from https://github.com/google/oauth2client

so I downloaded the updated version to my projected and added it's path .

Answer (score 0):

Are you invoking python2.7 or python3 when you import cloud debugger, or uritemplate directly?

```
$ python2.7 
>>> import uritemplate
>>> 
$ python3 
>>> import uritemplate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named uritemplate
```

Please note that Cloud debugger (and uritemplate) is for python 2.7.